# Error en plantilla "no arguments depend on a template parameter"

Tags: c++, lista, loops

hay un ejercicio que intenté hacer y que no me compila, a pesar de corregir varios fallos tontos, pero la cuestión es que falla debido a (creo yo) errores en el planteamiento.

este el enunciado:

> Desarrollar   el  método  template      void    dll_t::swap(const    int i,  const   int j)
>   que   intercambia el  valor   del atributo     data
>   del   nodo    i-ésimo (nodo   en  la  posición    i   de  la  lista)  con el  nodo    j-ésimo.

```
#pragma once

#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

#include "dll_node_t.hpp"

using namespace std;

namespace AED {

    template <class T>
    class dll_t {
    private:
        dll_node_t<T>* head_;
        dll_node_t<T>* tail_;

        int sz_;

    public:
        dll_t(void);
        dll_t(const dll_t& L);
        virtual ~dll_t(void); 

        void insert_tail(dll_node_t<T>*);
        void insert_head(dll_node_t<T>*);

        dll_node_t<T>* extract_tail(void);
        dll_node_t<T>* extract_head(void);

        dll_node_t<T>* get_tail(void);
        dll_node_t<T>* get_head(void);

        bool empty(void) const ;
        int get_nz (void) const{}

        void unlink(dll_node_t<T>*);
        dll_node_t<int>* find (const int v);
        void dll_union (dll_t<int>& A, dll_t<int>& B, dll_t<int>& C);
        int get_size(void) const; 
        void swap (const int i,const int j);

        // esto: contar los nonzeros
        //modif: suma elementos matriz 

        //double suma (void) const; // esto pa arriba


        //int get_np (void) const;
        //double suma_mat (void) const;
        void invert(void);




        ostream& write(ostream& os) const;
    };

    template<class T>

    void dll_t<T>::swap(const int i,const int j){
        dll_node_t<T>* aux = NULL;
        dll_node_t<T>* auxi = get_data();
        dll_node_t<T>* auxj = get_data();

        while(aux != NULL){
            while(auxi != NULL && auxj!=NULL){
                auxi->get_data()=aux;

                auxi->get_data() = aux->get_data();

                aux = auxj ->get_data();

                auxj = auxj -> get_next();
                auxi = auxi -> get_next();


            }
            aux = aux -> get_next();
        }
    }

    template<class T> 

    void dll_t<int>::dll_union (dll_t<int>& A, dll_t<int>& B, dll_t<int>& C){
        dll_node_t<int>* aux1 = A.get_head();
        dll_node_t<int>* aux2 = B.get_head();

        while (aux2 != NULL || aux1 != NULL){
            if (B.find((aux1->get_data()))){
                C.insert_tail(aux1);
            }



            if((aux1->get_data()) != (aux2->get_data())){
                C.insert_tail(aux1);
                C.insert_tail(aux2);
            }

            aux2=aux2->get_next();
            aux1=aux1->get_next(); 
        }
    }

    template<class T>

    dll_node_t<int>* dll_t<int> :: find(const int v){

        assert(!empty());

        dll_node_t <int>* aux = get_head();
        dll_node_t <int>* encontrado = NULL;

        while(aux !=NULL){
            if ((aux -> get_data())== v){
                encontrado= aux;
            }
            aux = aux-> get_next();
        }

        return encontrado;
    }


    template<class T>

    void dll_t<T> :: invert(void){

        assert(!empty());

        dll_node_t<T>* aux = get_tail();

        while (aux != NULL){
            extract_tail(aux);
            aux = aux -> get_prev();
        }

        while (aux !=NULL){
            insert_tail(aux);
            aux=aux->get_next();
        }
    }


template <class T>
    dll_t<T>::dll_t(void) :
    head_(NULL),
    tail_(NULL),
    sz_(0) {
    }

template <class T>
dll_t<T>::dll_t(const dll_t& L) :
head_(NULL),
tail_(NULL),
sz_(0) {

   dll_node_t<T>* aux = L.head_;

    while (aux != NULL) {
        insert_tail(new dll_node_t<T>(aux->get_data()));
        aux = aux->get_next();
    }
}



 template <class T>
    dll_t<T>::~dll_t(void) {

        dll_node_t<T>* aux = NULL;

        while (head_ != NULL) {
            aux = head_;
            head_ = head_->get_next();
            delete aux;
            aux = NULL;
        }
        sz_ = 0;
        head_ = NULL;
        tail_ = NULL;
    }
```

los errores que me da el método swap son estos:

```
In member function 'void AED::dll_t<T>::swap(int, int)':
64  37  [Error] there are no arguments to 'get_data' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'get_data' must be available [-fpermissive]

64  37   (if you use '-fpermissive', G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)

65  37      [Error] there are no arguments to 'get_data' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'get_data' must be available [-fpermissive]

86  10      [Error] prototype for 'void AED::dll_t<int>::dll_union(AED::dll_t<int>&, AED::dll_t<int>&, AED::dll_t<int>&)' does not match any in class 'AED::dll_t<int>'
40  8       [Error] candidate is: void AED::dll_t<T>::dll_union(AED::dll_t<int>&, AED::dll_t<int>&, AED::dll_t<int>&) [with T = int]
```

Este es el método `get_data();`

```
template <class T>
T dll_node_t<T>::get_data(void) const
{
    return data_;
}
```

Gracias

Comment: puedes poner tambien tu `main.cpp`?

Comment: ¿Cuál es la definición de `get_data`?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster  ya edité la pregunta y puse el método get_data();

Comment: @Renato.A ya edité la pregunta y puse el método get_data();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El método `get_data()` no está declarado, ni privado ni público.

Además, parece ser que necesita un parámetro que no se le está pasando.

Comment: si esta declarado como publico, y dice que no recibe parametros, deberias haber puesto esto como un comentario, no como una respuesta

Comment: Pero es que en esta línea `dll_node_t<T>* auxi = get_data();` se está usando como una función independiente, no como un método, y no está declarada. También, quería decir que _no_ se le está pasando el parámetro; perdón.